# enable to access public dns in browser amazon aws

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, aws-directory-service

I am a newbie here in this server and networking things. I have signed up in amazon aws and went through some basic documentations. There I could create security groups, instance, and web servers. I have installed LAMP with PuTTY. Everything going fine, but I am not able to access my public dns in browser. But in document, it says that I will see an apache homepage. I have pinged it. The result was "**Request Timed Out**". Why is it so? This is my inbound table:

[image]

Why it is not showing on browser? Any one can help?

Comment: Does your instance has a valid fqdn ? If exists does fqdn nslookup on the instance returns your Public DNS value. ? Or assign an elastic IP and check the IP in the browser.

Comment: OH DEAR, this really prove you are new to network. You need to read more.  A PING need ICMP-echo to be allow in security-group. And there is much more issue here that I doubt this question may cover.

Answer (score 2):

You need a beginners guide to AWS. I cover this in my [Wordpress/AWS guide](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/). Things to look at include your internet gateway and routing, which are covered in the tutorial.